# What Does it Mean for a Function to have Finite Support?

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on a problem that states:

Let $f$ be integrable over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. Show that there is a simple function $\eta$ on $\mathbb{R}$ which has finite support and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert f - \eta \rvert < \varepsilon$

What does it mean for a simple function $\eta$ to have finite support? I do not need help with the actual problem, just the meaning. Unfortunately, Royden's fourth edition of 'Real Analysis' does not describe this.

Comment: Are you sure they don't mean "bounded support"?

Comment: I copied it straight from the book. If you are curious, it is found on page 95, section 4.6, problem 44 (i) of Royden's Analysis fourth edition.

Comment: The numbering must really have changed... I can't seem to find subsections of section 4, nor any problem numbered 44 in my edition :)

Comment: I bought the international edition, that could be why.

Answer (score 6):

It should mean

> the function vanishes outside a set of finite measure

but not that only finitely many elements in the domain produce a nonzero value for the function.

We are talking about a measure theory book, after all. The main gauge on the size of a measurable set is its measure.

Of course, if the measure being used is the *counting measure* then it would turn into "only finitely many values of the domain produce nonzero values.

Answer (score 1):

*Finite support* just means that the function's domain has a finite number of values that produce non-zero values in the range.  So $f$ being integrable (i.e. finite valued) suggests that you can bound the domain of your simple function to finite support and still get your convergence.

Comment: That would imply $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert f - \eta \rvert = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert f \rvert$, since the domain where $\eta$ would have a nonnegative value would be a countable set with measure 0.

Comment: In my older edition (2nd), Royden refers to simple functions vanishing outside a set of finite measure.  That would be *bounded* support, as ncmathsadist indicated, but perhaps he's using *finite support* as a definition for this (bad one, in my view).

Answer (score 1):

In the fourth edition Royden's book, it is written (on p. 79):

> "It is convenient to say that a function that vanishes outside a set of finite measure has finite support and define its support
> to be $\{x: \ f(x) \neq 0\}$".

Thus, a measurable function of finite support means a measurable function supprted on a set of finite measure.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia defines support as the subsetset of the domain where the function is not equal to zero (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)).

Therefore, if a real function $f:\ \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ has a finite support, then there's a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ where it is not zero, and everywhere else it is mapped to zero.

E.g. a function $f$ that is equal to $x^{2}+1$ when $|x|<1$ and zero everywhere else, has finite support, since it is non-zero in the set $(-1, 1)$, and zero in $\mathbb{R}\backslash(-1, 1)$. To be precise, the set $(-1, 1)$ is the function's support (supp($f$)).

In your example, you can show that for all functions that vanish at infinity, like $f$, that is $\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}f=0$, it is true that the intgral
$
\int_{a}^{\infty}f\, dx
$
decreases as $a$ increases ($\exists\delta>0$ such as this is true $\forall a>\delta$), and the same holds for negative infinity. Thus, try assigning to $\eta$
$
\eta= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      f, & x\in (-q, q) \\
      0, & x\in \mathbb{R}\backslash(-q, q)
\end{array} 
\right. 
$

so that the integral of their absolute difference $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f-\eta|\, dx$ decreases as $q$ increases. Hence, you have a function $\Phi(q)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f-\eta|\, dx,\ q>0$, that is decreasing. From this point on, try a theorem (e.g. Bolzano's theorem) to show that $\Phi:\ (0, \infty)\rightarrow(0, \max(\Phi))$, is equal to $\epsilon$ at at least one point.

Comment: Regarding you example, the interval $(-1,1) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is not finite.

Comment: @Alex it is not finite, but it has finite measure(i.e. 2) and hence it is an example of function with finite support.