# Is There a Common Definition of "Finite Support"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

I thought I understood this term, but when I tried to verify this I found three different and conflicting definitions, none corresponding to mine. Is there a generally agreed definition for this term (and since it can't have all four meanings, what would be terms for the other cases) ?

Ref(1): Basic Set Theory  By Nikolai Konstantinovich Vereshchagin, Alexander Shen

A mapping f: A →  B has finite support if  it equals the least element in B for all but a finite subset of elements of A. *Requires obviously that B have some form of order and a least element.*

Ref(2): Wiki:
Suppose that f : X → R is a real-valued function whose domain is an arbitrary set X. The set-theoretic support of f, written supp(f), is the set of points in X where f is non-zero

Ref(3): [What Does it Mean for a Function to have Finite Support?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543535/what-does-it-mean-for-a-function-to-have-finite-support)

It should mean :
the function vanishes outside a set of finite measure
not that only finitely many elements in the domain produce a nonzero value for the function.

(4): My own understanding

f: A →  B has finite support if its domain is a finite subset of A.

Comment: Reference two is normally the definition you give just before saying what it means for a function to have *compact support* which means it only takes non-zero values on a subset of the domain whose closure is compact. It's a common definition in topology/geometry.

Comment: If you restrict reference 1 to $f\colon A \to \{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x\geq 0\}$ and similarly for reference two (with the usual ordering on $\mathbb{R}$), then the two notions of support coincide.

Comment: @DanielRust In that case, the support is usually taken to be the _closure_ of the set of points where $f$ is non-zero. Otherwise the set of continuous functions with compact support is a bit too small to be interesting.

Comment: In (4), isn't the domain of $f: A \to B$ just $A$ itself? In that case, requiring the domain of $f$ to be a finite subset of $A$ would be the same as requiring $A$ to be finite, which is probably not required for the usual notion of "finite support" to make sense.

Comment: Never use the "finite measure" definition without explaining it first.  It should be considered a non-standard usage except perhaps in a specialized area.

Answer (score 1):

The term "finite support" often appears in probability theory. Let me try to explain this concept in your preferred language.

Let $f:A\to B$ be a specific function and there exists a zero in $B$,

then, $f$ has finite support if $f(a)=0$ for all $a\in A\setminus X$, where $X$ is a finite set.

So your definition $(4)$ is not accurate enough, mathematically. In fact, the function's domain is still $A$.

The first three definitions mean similar things and are all correct.